Basic Blocks: Interrupted by "pointless" goto?
So I was studying some about compiler optimizations and as part of that, Control Flow Graphs (CFG's).
Specifically, I saw a "basic block" being defined as "a straight-line code sequence with no branches in except to the entry and no branches out except at the exit" (this phrasing is from the Wikipedia entry on "basic block"). I then saw several descriptions of algorithms for finding such blocks, and they generally revolve around determining the leaders and then considering them and everything that follows them up until the next leader/EoF to be their block, with a leader being defined as fulfilling one of several conditions like "being the target of a jump", "being the first line of code", or "being the line that follows a jump".
I was then considering the (perhaps nitpicky) case of a "pointless" goto; something like:
10:    if x > y then goto 11
11:    print("oh noes!")

This is:

A goto, and so technically a jump, I think.
Not really a branch, since both options lead to line #11.

So if I were to split this into two basic blocks, they'd have a single directed edge from 11 to 12, with the start of block 11 being their sole entry point, and the end of block 12 their sole exit point – which seems to imply that I might as well not have separated them in the first place.
So if I go with the definition of a leader and with the common algorithms I see, the above should be classified as two blocks. If I go with the definition of a basic block that I usually see, then the above can be a single basic block: only one entry point and one exit point.
So, I suppose this whole definition in the first place is mostly a tool and so that the definition (as with even much more "accuracy-reliant" mathematics, where such differences might be very substantial) may vary, and that whether to consider this a single basic block or two basic blocks may therefore likewise vary; but I wonder if there's an "accepted" or "conventional" way to think about this.

Afterthought: does this fit more in cs.stackexchange.com than here?
